# Node.js server emit data to backbone model

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to integrate socket.io with backbone.js, so basicly I have a node server that gets data from a database and emit the data to a backbone client, the client's model should somehow retrieve the incoming data but I'm not sure how to put socket.io in the model now, just getting confused after lost of tries. Any expert please enlight me would be much appreciated!

Node server emit data to client in url /pics

```
app.get('/pics', function(req, res){
    db.collection('pics', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
              socket.emit('news', items);
            });  
        });
    }); 
});
```

Client in Backbone model should retrieve the emitted data(this model works for normal http data sending):

```
window.Pic = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/pics",
    idAttribute: "_id",
    initialize: function (){},
    defaults: {
        _id: null,
        name: "",
        date: "",
    }
});

window.PicCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Pic,
    url: "/pics"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I must admit using Backbone on node + socket.io is quite interesting. Still haven't put my mind into it though. First thing first, have you considered using a plugin Backbone for websockets? Some people have created such.

To give another approach, I think you don't really have much of a choice. Using socket.io to listen to incoming data would result in something like that:

```
socket.on('model', function(attributes) {
  // do something
});
```

So you'd have to have access to some collection where you could update manually your model.

If you wish to really use socket.io INSIDE your model, a more transparent way would be to extend your model to start listening to some custom event on its creation. I'll link a jsfiddle to show what could be done.

**Edit:** [here you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/tYhpz/)
Note that this is full of boilerplate. I'm trying to figure out a way to do a generic socketModel. I'll update if I find one.

Comment: thanks for reply! It's interesting to see how others do it :)

Comment: It is. But it would also depends on what you have server-side. I mean, you could use Backbone on the server too, and that could be a wonderful combination. Still haven't put my mind into it though.